Choosing an OIDC flow for WebAuthn when using Keycloak
I am new to OIDC and WebAuthn. I want to provide a progressive passwordless experience for my users. I understand that passkeys are supported by Windows/Mac/iOS/Android.
I want to configure a Keycloak client so that it can authenticate using OIDC flows. But I have two questions.

Which OIDC flow should I be using? I know using Implicit flow is bad. What choice do I have given I cannot use authorization grant flow as I am developing a mobile app. Opening a web view on the phone app to provide fingerprint seems odd to me.

How should I configure the authentication override for my Keycloak client such that the default fallback is a username and password. But if the user has a passkey, then it will default to such mechanism?



Are you trying to use native platform APIs or web-based experiences (e.g. WebViews)?

Both. Web UIs for browsers and native platform APIs for mobile apps.

An app runs the authorization code flow whenever it wants to authenticate users. With passkeys it works like this:

Authorization server receives the authorization request and returns HTML forms to the browser that implement passkeys UX guidelines. The user then invokes browser dialogs. These dialogs interact with OS platform passkey APIs or FIDO2 APIs if an external device (eg a yubikey) is used.

In a mobile app, run the code flow in a Chrome Custom Tab or ASWebAuthenticationSession window and it looks quite integrated.


You are right that it is not quite native passkeys. For that to work, OAuth messages would need to work differently:

The authorization server would need to return non-HTML responses to enable the app to render native screens that interact with OS platform passkeys or FIDO2 APIs.

In future I expect browserless flows to be possible with OAuth, but that is not covered by standards yet. Until then, use a browser-based approach and implement a code flow. You then externalize passkeys complexity to the authorization server and get a correct access token with which to call your APIs.
